# CanCan executes unwanted count(*) sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

ability.rb:

```
can :index, Product, Product.owned_by(user) do |obj|
  obj.owned_by?(user)
end
```

When I call can?(:index, Product) CanCan sends

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products` WHERE ...
```

In navigation bar I have lot of items and each of them has can?(:index,...)that slows my page.

Something wrong in ability.rb?

Comment: It makes sense that it would have to query each time, but maybe you could limit it by caching the nav bar

Comment: May be you are right. I can cache navbar for each role in my application.

Comment: In cancan/rule.rb: matches_conditions?(action, subject, extra_args)

@conditions.empty? - produces count() query